# Android Two Fragment listview layout Excpetion

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments, android-contacts, android-support-library

I got a wierd problem..I am making a Custom Contact app and I refactored my app today using Fragments...I used Communicator design pattern for passing ID of the contact selected to the Contact Details Fragmet at right to display the details of Contact...The app now works perfect in smartphones where I had placed single activity layout but if I run the same in Tablet(layout-large has a 2fragments in it) its force closing and it tells some wired errors..Tried searching it in google it and got fed up..I shall post the Log info here pls help me..Some issues with v4 support library and Sqlite query but couldnt sort out..Pls help..If you specifically need any code tell me, I shall post it

```
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.mysamplelistfragment/com.example.mysamplelistfragment.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2575)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2603)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2089)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:170)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:140)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:366)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:370)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:313)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at com.example.mysamplelistfragment.ContactDetailsFragment.onResume(ContactDetailsFragment.java:57)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performResume(Fragment.java:1543)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:963)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1104)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1086)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchResume(FragmentManager.java:1894)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onResumeFragments(FragmentActivity.java:466)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPostResume(FragmentActivity.java:455)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:5095)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:2565)
11-26 00:00:38.377: E/AndroidRuntime(3273):     ... 12 more
```

Comment: Post this class ContactDetailsFragment

Comment: Thanks foor identifying the place where there was an Error..Actually I had over ridden onResume of Fragment just as I do with Activty..tat caused all the prooblem..now iits solved

Comment: Yeah, that'll do it! Glad to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overridden onCreate of fragment like onCreate of Activity. ... both are different please understand